# Using LED bike lights with a dynamo instead of batteries

Tags: hacking

Today, I stayed too long chatting at a friend's house which caused me to ride home in the dark.

Unfortunately the batteries on the lights were quite drained so the lights barely worked.

Then I noticed that I still had my old dynamo attached. Couldn't that be used to power the lights? After some research I found out that it was possible according to [this page](https://www.natuurkunde.nl/opdrachten/785/nooit-meer-fietsen-in-het-donker).

Disclaimer: it is in Dutch but here is the schematic:

[image: Schematisch of the research]

This schematic shows that I need a rectifier to turn the AC of the bike dynamo into usable DC.

For safety I also would like to add a capacitor which keeps the lights on for 5 minutes maximum so you won't sit in the dark near a busy crossing or a light stop.

So this brings me to the following problems.

- Is there a rectifier available that works on a bike dynamo?
- Isn't the changing voltage of the dynamo going to cause issues?
- How many microfarads would you need to power it all?

Comment: This is not answerable without a lot of engineering detail, particularly of the target lights.  As such information is not typically available for consumer products, questions on the usage of consumer products have been ruled to be off topic here.  This question would only survive if you could give meaningful details about not only the dynamo, but the *internals* of the target lights.  Realistically since a dynamo is a complex piece of equipment which can fail, you're better off with a second, small backup battery light.  I have a little AA LED one could ride moderate speeds with.

Comment: Maybe useful to note: I read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58718/building-a-new-dynamo-bike-light) but since it is over 7 years old I wonder if it isn't to outdated by new electronics in the past 7 years.

Comment: Some extra information: a standard Dutch bicycle dynamo has a loaded output of 6V, 0.5A AC (3W). Without a load, it is about 8V AC. A fairly large air gap makes sure not much more power is delivered when you go fast. You can probably see what voltage your light units expect from the batteries used.

Comment: You may try to charge your battery with the dynamo with the. LEDs on or off. You might get a few watts with a load

Comment: @ocrdu Good information! The lights are your standard Hema led lights (of which I am very fond of) powered by 3 1,5v battery's. So 3 x 1,5v = 4,5v

Comment: You mean this? https://www.hema.com/en-gb/hobby-leisure/cycling/bike-lights/set-led-lights.-41198091.html. Can you tell how they are connected internally and if there are other components apart from the three leds and one or more resistors? Because if there is no other electronics involved and we can devise the current, a simple constant current source can be built with a couple of transistors in a way that is very resilient to supply voltage variations.

Comment: No no no! This is the front one: [https://www.hema.com/en-gb/hobby-leisure/cycling/bike-lights/led-headlight-41198092.html] and this is the back one [https://www.hema.com/en-gb/hobby-leisure/cycling/bike-lights/bicycle-rear-light-41188020.html]

Comment: Error 404. Please edit the question adding a description of the lights.  If possible, open them and post a picture of the way the LEDs are connected. Are you capable of measuring the current supplied by the batteries?

Comment: Sorry, typo: unloaded about 18V AC, not 8V AC. 18V AC is the highest I measured, anyway. They are designed for delivering 2.4W to the front light plus 0.6W to the rear light, both 6V bulbs.

Comment: Bicycle dinamo output voltage varies, depends of speed. Old times light bulb was connected straight to dynamo but it was incandescent. You may need some simple current restriction circuit, just resistor is not enough

Answer (score 3):

LEDs need to have current limiting to work properly, so your system as shown would blow up the LED in short order.

You also wish to have some extra hold-up time for your system, which implies a secondary battery. This needs a battery charge control to prevent overcharging your battery. Again, hooking up to the unregulated rectified dynamo is a bad idea, you could damage or explode your battery.

Instead, my thought would be to use a USB-chargeable LED light, and convert your dynamo output to regulated 5V DC to charge the light while you’re riding. Then you have a pre-engineered solution for your lamp and a much simpler problem to solve for your dynamo. In fact, this is a product you can buy pre-made. Bonus: charge your phone too.

Comment: Personally i mainly wanted to do this simply for the creative challenge but do you have a recommendation on a converter? I saw [https://www.conrad.com/p/kemo-m-172n-usb-bicycle-charge-controller-black-1007807](this) one but I am curious about your suggestions!

Comment: I just did a Google for 5V bicycle dynamo charger and a bunch of results came up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to light LEDs via the bottle dynamo, bypassing the need for batteries.
We use a full bridge rectifier to turn the alternating voltage from the dynamo into a reasonably flat - albeit speed-dependent - voltage. And then a constant current regulator feeds the current to the LEDs in parallel.

I am assuming the voltage supplied by the dynamo is roughly sinusoidal with a peak varying between 4 to 8 V, but the circuit as we will see is very resilient with respect to voltage variation. Since I had no certain data about the frequency (I guess it depends on the type of dynamo) I did not even bother computing the capacitors' values. I used a reasonably high but not humongous values.

As for the frequency, bottle dynamos runs at significantly higher rpms than the more modern hub dynamos. In the simulation below I erroneously used a frequency of 3200 Hz, because I miscalculated the rpm.
Edit: A more reasonable frequency can be computed considering that at 15km/h, i.e. 4.16 m/s a wheel of 70 cm in diameter (perimeter of 2.2 m) will rotate at about 113 rpm. With a gear ratio of 50:1, the bottle dynamo will turn at 5600 rpm (not rps!!!) and this translates to a frequency of less than 95 revolutions per second. What we will see at the output might depend on the internal construction of the dynamo but the beauty of this circuit is that the capacitors in the rectifier and the independence of voltage supply of the regulator won't make this matter.

[image: LED driver from bottle dynamo]
The bridge rectifier (and optional voltage doubler) can be put into a pillbox under the seat, while the constant current generator(s) can be cast into a silicon mold and placed wherever you see fit.

Any PNP capable of sustaining the currents and powers involved will do. By setting R2 = 22 ohms we get a current output of about 30 mA, which gets divided between the three white LEDs with a nominal voltage of 3.2V. I did not even bother to use balancing resistors because if the LEDs come from the same batch, they will be reasonably similar and you won't notice the difference in luminosity (you can add a series resistance of a ohm or so if you are bothered).

This is how the current in each LED (and other circuit parameters) changes with the voltage output of the dynamo for temperatures comprised between -15°C and 25°C.

[image: values as dynamo peak voltage changes]

You won't mind the difference in luminosity when your speed changes - what's more important is that even if you speed up at 50 km/h you will have roughly the same current in the LEDs. I have used this regulator to power LED fairy lights and I can crank up the voltage without any problem. You won't lose your headlight when you are speeding down a slope in the dark (as it happened to me with incandescent lightbulbs)

If we look near the 6V mark we see the current it's reasonably constant.

[image: current near the 6V mark]

And if look at the time domain we see that even with the significant ripple at the very low frequency of 75 Hz, the current in the LEDs is not significantly altered (for the purpose).

[image: ripple in time domain]

If you want to reduce ripple, add capacitors in parallel.

If you find that this circuit does not provide enough light at very low speed (well, that is also what happened in the past, with incandescent bulbs) you might want to add a voltage doubler stage.

My suggestion is to arrange the circuit in blocks:

Dynamo --> Optional Voltage Doubler --> Bridge rectifier -> Two constant current modules for front- and back- lights.

If you use red LEDs you can put them in three parallel rows of two LEDs each. With a voltage doubler you could add a series resistance on each row in the front and back LEDs.

This is all I can say without having precise data on the voltage and frequency provided by your bottle dynamo at the speeds you usually run at. Also, since you did not provide any info on how your lights are wired, this circuit require you to wire the LEDs yourself.

Comment: Same thing, (arguably) less effort: use a cheap voltage regulator, in the two-terminal constant-current configuration. You can even buy a single component "constant current diode", which is roughly the same thing as the transistor circuit shown in the excellent answer above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider.  Firstly you shouldn’t drive a LED directly from a power source, you must always have some current-limiting - in the simplest case a resistor, which will probably be fine for your application.  Secondly, the dynamo will likely be rated for a specific load, e.g. 6VAC for a 600mA load; if the load is less then the voltage will be somewhat higher.  A capacitor won’t be enough to keep the LED lit for a few minutes, you’ll need a battery.

Years ago I rigged up my Walkman to my bicycle dynamo and it worked well enough with 4 AA NiCD cells.  If you want to do the job properly though you’d want to make sure you didn’t overcharge the battery.  It’s certainly possible but not as simple as your schematic suggests.

Comment: @ocrdu noted this on the commends above: “A standard Dutch bicycle dynamo has a loaded output of 6V, 0.5A AC (3W). Without a load, it is about 8V AC. A fairly large air gap makes sure not much more power is delivered when you go fast. “

As the the lights. They are in total powered by 5 1,5v batteries (3 in the front and 2 in the back)