# Twenty-two 3 V LEDs in series with 9 V power supply

Tags: led, resistance, series

I am wiring twenty-two 3 V mini LEDs in series. I cannot find any other values for these LEDs. What resistor value I would need using a 9 V power supply?

Comment: Are you sure you mean _series_?

Comment: Well, you realize that 22*3 V is 66 V?  So you'll need a boost converter or a higher voltage power supply to get them to light up.

Comment: I suggest you wire them all in parallel (it can be done quite neatly and you end up with a clean string of LEDs) and then  power them with a constant current driver (two transistors and two resistors) that will set the current for many possible voltage sources (say from 3.3V to 9V including 5V USB). This works like a charm when you do not need high currents in each led, say 1- 4 mA each. I have 'bottle lamps' made this way and the 50 led one draws less than 40 mA).

Comment: Something like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540491/using-led-bike-lights-with-a-dynamo-instead-of-batteries/540758#540758 but without the bridge rectifier. Of course in order to put them all in parallel the LED must be all alike, from the same batch preferably, otherwise you would need different resistors for every color (I did one of those as well but the string is no longer neat).

Answer (score 3):

Wiring 22 LEDs in series will require a drive voltage of ~22x the forward voltage of one LED at a given current.

For a 3V LED, that means you would need a 66V power supply. If all of the LEDs must be in series, your 9V supply will not be enough on its own, and no amount of resistors will help you.

You have two choices. Either change your power supply to one capable of supplying a higher voltage (or use a DC/DC to step up the voltage), or alternatively wire the LEDs in an array of parallel strings.

For example you could wire the LEDs in series pairs, each pair having a resistor to limit the current. Then place 11 such pairs in parallel. This would be achievable using a 9V supply (albeit a bit wasteful - 33% of the power is dumped in the resistors). Depending on the forward voltage vs current for the LEDs, you could possibly use 8 parallel groups of 3 LEDs each with a small series resistor, but 9V might not quite be enough for that. (Note: resistor values assumed a 20mA I<sub>f</sub>, change as appropriate).

[image: LED Arrays - 2 x 11, and 3 x 8, with resistor for each chain]

You could do something similar with a higher voltage supply - for example with a 20V supply you could have strings of 6 in series (6 x 3V = 18V) with a current limiting resistor, and have four parallel strings (uses 24 LEDs, and gives 90% efficiency).

Depending on the power of the LEDs, you may want to use a constant-current driver circuit instead of a resistor. This would still require a supply voltage higher than the total V<sub>f</sub> of the number of LEDs in series, but will give more precise regulation of the current.

Comment: Wow, ok. So What I am trying to do is build and led circuit that borders a wooden welcome sign that turned out to  22 3V mini LEDs. What would the easiest way to wire it using the lowest voltage I can to light them.

Comment: @Reaper161 simplest solution is to wire them as an array of parallel chains as shown - e.g. 11 pairs of LEDs, each pair having its own resistor. You'd need to know the rated current for the LEDs in order to work out the resistor value.

Comment: The only info I can find about the LEDs that I have is this. 3V 3mm LED. I have tried to find a data sheet or any other info than what I have. I cannot measure current with my multimeter right now because I let a friend use it and he blew the fuse. I

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5HwZt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: PWM voltage]

[image: LED and Input Current]

This is a simple boost converter that can drive a string of 22 3 volt LEDs at about 20 mA, from a 9 V battery. It's a 25 kHz PWM with about 5% duty cycle. The output is 1.3 watts and the input appears to be just 27 mA (9V * 60 mA *0.05). So there must be some problem with the simulation, and I'll need to try it in LTspice.

The best way to implement this might be with a small microcontroller where the PWM is generated and adjusted for the desired current.

Here is a corrected simulation in LTspice:

[image: LED string with inductor and PWM]

Answer (score 0):

The cheap battery powered ‘fairy lights’ you buy at craft stores typically run the LEDs in parallel on a pair of 1.5V cells (3-ish volts, depending on the freshness of the battery.) There will usually be a small dropping resistor (10-20 ohm) for the entire string. These fairy lights can run for a very long time. I suggest you will be happier with this arrangement than if you try to use a 9V cell.

If you insist on the 9V cell, you would connect 21 or 24 LEDs as three sets of 7 or 8 in parallel, the sets then wired in series, with a dropping resistor of 30-60 ohms for the whole thing. Run time won’t be so great though.

If you want more efficiency by wiring them in series, you’ll need to consider a boost converter. A bigger light string might have one, and be powered by USB 5V or by 3x 1.5V cells.